# Is a dryer connection with the G and W connected at the plug safe?

Tags: dryer

I have a dryer plug ,4 prong that is looped from ground to neutral .is this safe?

Comment: There are lots of questions already asked and answered on this topic. Have you searched? See the Related list in the sidebar, too.

Comment: No, it's not safe. Get it fixed. It's functionally similar to having a 3-prong dryer cord with no ground, and those have been outlawed in new construction for decades, for good reasons. They were never a good idea, even when they were legal due to manufacturer pressure. Enough actual deaths ensued that they were banned.

Comment: How is you outlet wired?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should my dryer cord's neutral and ground be connected to the same terminal?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/146139/should-my-dryer-cords-neutral-and-ground-be-connected-to-the-same-terminal)

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring in question please?